# Compute list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to compute list of all triples [X,Y,Z] in prolog for some game and the challenge is to

X, Y,, and Z are different integers between 0 and 9  (both included), and
     (10*X+Y)/(10*Y+Z) equals X/Z.

```
?- good_triples(L).
L = [[1, 6, 4], [1, 9, 5], [2, 6, 5], [4, 9, 8]].
```

somthing like this and i started the code but not sure about how to do it if any clue to help :

```
good_list(L):- creat_triples([X,Y,Z],L).

creat_triples([X,Y,Z],L): X=< 9 ,Y=< 9 ,Z=< 0,
X>=0 , Y>=0,Z>=0,
```

Answer (score 2):

We can change the check for `(10*X+Y)/(10*Y+Z) = X/Z` to avoid divide by zero if we multiply both sides by `(10*Y+Z)*Z`. We, therefore, check for `(10*X+Y)*Z = (10*Y+Z)*X`.

Using the clp(fd) library for SWI Prolog allows a way to generate the desired triples under the given constraints:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

create_tuple(L) :-  % Expects create_tuple([X1,X2,...,Xn])
    L ins 0..9,
    all_distinct(L).

good_triple([X,Y,Z]) :-
    create_tuple([X,Y,Z]),
    (10*X+Y)*Z #= (10*Y+Z)*X,
    label([X,Y,Z]).
```

If you are avoiding the clp(fd) library, you can still be a little more compact by using `select/3` to ensure that the integers chosen from the domain are distinct:

```
create_triple([X,Y,Z]) :-
    select(X, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], D1),
    select(Y, D1, D2),
    member(Z, D2).

good_triple([X,Y,Z]) :-
    create_triple([X,Y,Z]),
    (10*X+Y)*Z =:= (10*Y+Z)*X. % Check for numeric expression result equality with =:=
```

A query to `good_triple(L)` yields:

```
?- good_triple(L).
L = [1, 6, 4] ;
L = [1, 9, 5] ;
L = [2, 6, 5] ;
L = [4, 9, 8] ;
false.
```

Then, as Eugene shows, you can gather the solutions into a single list using `setof`:

```
good_triples(L) :-
    setof(T, good_triple(T), L).
```

Yielding:

```
?- good_triples(L).
L = [[1, 6, 4], [1, 9, 5], [2, 6, 5], [4, 9, 8]].
```

Comment: still the problem with 3 parameters , and i want it to be with only one .

Comment: @Nik, See my updated answer. It will work just as you describe in your problem statement: you just query, `good_triples(L)` to get all the triples. The predicate head `good_triple([X,Y,Z]) :-...` simply indicates that `good_triple` has ONE argument that is a list of three elements, and is equivalent to defining, `good_triple(L) :- L = [X,Y,Z], ...`. Either way, it is necessary to extract `X`, `Y`, and `Z` list elements to do the computations. If that doesn't meet your needs, then if you could please explain in more detail what you want to see in your problem statement, it can be addressed.

Comment: @Nik, are there any remaining questions regarding my answer? Is it acceptable?

Comment: thnxx alot was more than enough

Answer (score 1):

Converting your requirements directly into Prolog rule without any possible optimizations:

```
digits([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]).

good_triple([X,Y,Z]) :-
    digits(D),          % D is the list of digits
    member(X,D),        % X, Y and Z are members of D
    member(Y,D),
    member(Z,D),
    X \=Y,              % The numbers are all different
    X \= Z,
    Y \= Z,
    Z \= 0,             % Z can't be zero, since we are going to divide by it
    Lhs is (10*X+Y)/(10*Y+Z),   % Left hand side of the equation
    Rhs is X/Z,                 % Right hand side of the equation
    Lhs = Rhs.                  % The equation
```

And now to collect all of the results:

```
setof(L, good_triple(L), R).
```

gives:

```
R = [[1, 6, 4], [1, 9, 5], [2, 6, 5], [4, 9, 8]]
```

Comment: I still want to do it with one parameter like this 

good_triples(L).

Comment: @Nik it already is with one parameter, `[X,Y,Z]` is one list, of length 3.